# automatic login and file download

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am trying to download file using webbrowser class.i could login and navigate further using webbrowser.

but the file is located on the website using javascript.

I tried to get file using `HttpWebRequest(fileurl)` using cookies from webbrowser.

the code for downloading file after login is as below.

```
string myUri = @"url_of_file";   
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);   
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
foreach (string cookie in webBrowser1.Document.Cookie.Split(';'))
{
    string name = cookie.Split('=')[0];
    string value = cookie.Substring(name.Length + 1);
    string path1 = "/";
    string domain = ".abcde.com"; //change to your domain name

    request.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(name.Trim(), value.Trim(), path1, domain));
}

WebResponse res = request.GetResponse();       

StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\file.csv");

while (sReader.Peek() >= 0)
sWriter.WriteLine(sReader.ReadLine());

sWriter.Close();
```

however the reponse stream does not have file instead it has the "url_of_file" in the html body.as below.

```
<html><head></head>
<body onload="this.location.href='/Marketinfo/SubViewSubscriptionFile?product_code=DOL_INT&amp;file_id=460916&amp;subscription_id=318342&amp;loadnow=true'">
</body></html>
```

Please someone suggest what is wrong in this

Answer (score 0):

So the next step is to spoof the server by using the existing cookies plus adding all the HTTP headers the server expects.
If you want to have a full view of the background in requests and responses open a Chrome browser, press Ctrl+Shift+I to open the Developer Tools, select the Network tab and repeat the process from scratch as a single user. By clicking on the files on the Name column you will get all the relative information for requests and responses. The benefit is that you will have whatever is needed to totally spoof the server without even using a Web Browser control.

Comment: thanks,i could download the file.since the response stream had oonload.true.i just apended the &loadnow=true fro url.It worked.